# Extracting columns of data using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-parsing

I have a text file called `data.txt` that looks like:

```
n   sin(n)  cos(n)
0   0   1
1   0.841470985 0.540302306
2   0.909297427 -0.416146837
3   0.141120008 -0.989992497
4   -0.756802495    -0.653643621
5   -0.958924275    0.283662185
6   -0.279415498    0.960170287
7   0.656986599 0.753902254
8   0.989358247 -0.145500034
9   0.412118485 -0.911130262
10  -0.544021111    -0.839071529
```

I am trying to extracting these columns of data into a pandas dataframe.

What I am doing right now is:

```
col1 = []
col2 = []
col3 = []

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        first, second, third = line.split()
        col1.append(first)
        col2.append(second)
        col3.append(third)

print(col1)
print(col2)
print(col3)
```

This code reads `data.txt` line by line and it gets pretty slow if I have huge data files.

Is there a way to streamline this using something like pandas? Is it possible to extract these columns using pandas?

Comment: Take a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html in particular the `sep` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should help you:

```
data = pd.read_csv('file_name.txt',sep= " ")
```

This will give you dataframe and its very easy to compute such problem using pandas dataframe.

**Good Luck**

Comment: this works! just that i had to change it to ```sep='\t'```